# How to read a CSV file to array in Java

Tags: java, regex, csv

Like the question says, how do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OpenCSV, it will be quick and easy

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Documents\\file.csv"));
List<String[]> csvValues = reader.readAll();
```

This code sample will give you a List with String arrays inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

Try [opencsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/). Seems like it'll do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class. Here's [an example](http://www.java-examples.com/parse-csv-file-using-stringtokenizer-example).

Comment: This isn't a complete implementation. In CSV it's possible to escape using quotes. The provided example doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: @Tarlog I did't say it was a complete implementation. It's just an example of how to use StringTokenizer in the OP's question context. StringTokenizer is one of the easier ways to go if you don't want to use any third party modules/libraries.

Comment: Yes, I understand: it's easy, but it doesn't work in this case. But it's easy... Oh yes: easy. But it doesn't work... Who cares, if it's easy?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/) provides [CsvReader](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/wink/tags/wink-1.1.2-incubating/wink-common/src/main/java/org/apache/wink/common/internal/providers/entity/csv/CsvReader.java) and [CsvWriter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/wink/tags/wink-1.1.2-incubating/wink-common/src/main/java/org/apache/wink/common/internal/providers/entity/csv/CsvWriter.java) utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use split() method on the read line to get the array. The method takes in the regular expression for splitting.